# Conditional Formatting in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, html, angular, html-table

Here is the conditional formatting feature in Microsoft Excel where the color bars represent the percentage in comparing to the highest value.

[image: Conditional formatting in excel]

Is there anyway to achieve this with HTML5 using either CSS or JavaScript? Or maybe using additional Angular library as well.

I'm thinking about using the [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to but this feature may not be widely supported on all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8mwxcjaz/1/)?

You can do this simple in vanillaJS. You must get all elements

```
const elNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
const elements = [...elNodes];
```

Get their values and find the max value

```
const elementsValues = elements.map((el) => parseFloat(el.children[1].textContent));
const maxValue = Math.max(...elementsValues);
```

Finally change the width of elements based on value:

```
elements.forEach((el) => {
    el.children[0].style.width = 100 / (maxValue / parseFloat(el.children[1].textContent)) + '%';
});
```

Comment: This seems to work as I expected in Chrome but in Edge it fails right at the line  `const elements = [...elNodes];` with an error `SCRIPT5002: Function expected test.html (13,13)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/misc/function-expected. What `...` means in javascript? it's really hard to google `...` :(

Comment: It's spread operator, that means when you have for example an array with values, the spread operator will extract them all. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

This is new feature, added in ES6, so you can replace it with:
const elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elNodes);
That do exactly the same thing in the result. 
The reason why you must do this is because we get a Node elements from a DOM, not an array, so you must convert them to use it like an array.